# Survey path planning for UAV with high turning radius

Tags: navigation, algorithm, path-planning, uav

I want to perform rectangular area survey. The sensor can either work with very narrow FOV or with wide FOV but requiring very high overlap.

My plane's turn diameter is much greater than required spacing for boustrophedon path. I would like what is optimal strategy for surveying with such constrain.

I would like to minimize time spent flying, while getting full coverage with required overlap. Bellow is ASCII image of necessary (scanning) part of the path.
I want to connect these lines in such a way as to visit every one exactly once while being unable to go from  line x to n neighboring lines on each side.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | |
```

For example if n=3 i can go like 0 → 5 → 1 → 6 → 2 → 7 → ...
but not 0 → 1 or 2 or 3
This above is a very specific case that in my opinion illustrates the situation well. I am however looking for a more general solution that works for most cases in witch surveyed space is wider than this (4*turn_radius+distance_between_tracks)

I was unable to find any papers on this specific subject, all papers I found assumed that UAV would be able tu turn sharply enough to enter next line without issues.

Comment: Can you lay out the cost function your hoping to minimize with this optimal strategy? What values would you like to drive your planning function?

Comment: @holmeski I hope my update answered your questions.

Comment: What papers have you found that relied on the sharp turn assumption?

Comment: @holmeski 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326166960_Optimal_Polygon_Decomposition_for_UAV_Survey_Coverage_Path_Planning_in_Wind  
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09224.pdf  
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ee6b/dd20dd58de3c4fe646103e76b46237821d38.pdf  This one mentions turning but in my case Ω turns are impractical as turning radius of my plane is ~7 times greater than desired distance between surveying lines. Here is Desmos ilustration of the problem: 
 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/penwvuamos

Comment: Do you need to travel directly along the lines of do you just need all of the ground covered?

Comment: I would prefer to travel along straight lines as it makes it easier to keep sensor pointing at the ground.

Comment: Can you solve this with A*?

Comment: How many survey lines will there be? If it's a small number, is simulating all paths possible?

Comment: I expect quite a few lines as surveyed area is quite big. For my test area I expect about 60 lines. Thankfully path can be calculated beforehand so planing phase taking more than few seconds is acceptable. I will try to redefine the problem in terms of traveling salesman problem. Hopefully it will be fast enough to plan the path in reasonable time.